# Manipulate Column According to other Columns in R

Tags: r, lapply

I have a table in R in following format :

```
    Name        Place      Num 
     Name_A     Place_1    231
     Name_A     Place_1    232
     Name_A     Place_2    233
     Name_A     Place_2    432
     Name_A     Place_2    433
     Name_X     Place_1    534
     Name_X     Place_1    535
```

For every Name and Place cols ,Num col is sorted and Continuous. I just want to change the Num col start from 1 and increment continously for every pair of Name and Place . Desired Output for above table :

```
      Name        Place      Num 
     Name_A     Place_1    1
     Name_A     Place_1    2
     Name_A     Place_2    1
     Name_A     Place_2    2
     Name_A     Place_2    3
     Name_X     Place_1    1
     Name_X     Place_1    2
```

Not here for loop soln. 
Any help appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
library(dplyr)
Data %>%
   group_by(Name,Place) %>%
   mutate(Num=row_number())
```